# How can I set APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY flag for only some targets using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm developing an app with three (non-test) targets: `App`, `Extension` and `Shared`. The `Shared` target is included in both the `App` and `Extension` and provides, as you'd expect, shared functionality that both use.

I'm using cocoapods.

I need to set `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=YES` in `Shared` and `Extension` in order to pass App Review and suppress warnings in Xcode.

I need to set `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=NO` in `App` because I need to access e.g. `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` from inside the app.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

abstract_target 'Foo' do
    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'PubNub', '~> 4.3'

        target :'Base' do
        end

        target :'App' do
            inherit! :search_paths
            pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~> 7.2'
            pod 'NYTPhotoViewer', '~> 1.1'
            pod 'Cloudinary', '~> 1.0'
            pod 'CTAssetsPickerController', '~> 3.3'
        end

        target :'Extension' do
        end
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'YES'
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
end

target :'App' do
   post_install do |installer|
       installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
           configuration.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
       end
   end
end
```

This fails because I am duplicating target names, I think. But how do I set this up to work properly?

Comment: @RDC thanks for code format cleanup. How do you do this efficiently?

Comment: Hey Thank you :) I just select the only code part in entire post and click on **{ }** button to just format the code, sometime you may need to adjust space etc.

Comment: Btw **why did you deleted your answer ?**, please un-delete it ,if it worked for you and accept it, so it may help in future to someone somewhere

Comment: I thought it was working but it only builds for the simulator, not for the device. I'll wait until I have a full solution before posting an answer!

Comment: @RDC working answer back, badder than ever, etc

Answer (score 4):

Key insights that made this work:

1. Instead of using `abstract_target` and embedding all three actual targets inside, I used `Shared` as my outer target, and nested `App` and `Extension` inside.
2. Instead of trying to figure out whether `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY` should be YES or NO in a single `post_install` hook, I use a post_install hook for each target, specifying whether the key should be YES or NO for that target.
3. Lots of cruft when changing the structure of the podfile. In the end I needed to `deintegrate` and `pod install` again before it would work.

Complete podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target :'Shared' do

    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'PubNub', '~> 4.3'
    pod 'Cloudinary', '~> 1.0'

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
            configuration.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'YES'
        end
    end

    target :'App' do
        pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', '~> 7.2'
        pod 'NYTPhotoViewer', '~> 1.1'
        pod 'CTAssetsPickerController', '~> 3.3'

        post_install do |installer|
            installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
                configuration.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
            end
        end
    end

    target :'Extension' do
        post_install do |installer|
            installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
                configuration.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'YES'
            end
        end
    end
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
end
```